# Writing sigma notation $\sum^n_{i=1} \frac {i}{2^i}$ in closed form

Tags: summation, closed-form

What would be a way to find the closed form of $\frac {1}{2} + \frac {2}{4}+\frac {3}{8}+\cdots+\frac {n}{2^n}=\sum^n_{i=1} \frac {i}{2^i}=s$

I've looked at $\frac {s}{2}=\frac {1}{4} + \frac {2}{8}+\frac {3}{16}+\cdots+\frac {n}{2^{n+1}}$

And then $s-\frac {s}{2}=\frac {s}{2}=\frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{8}+\cdots+\frac {1}{2^n}-\frac {n}{2^{n+1}}$

Any idea where to go from here?
Please, if you are sure of where I'm trying to go with this, just ask.

Comment: I assume you mean $i/2^i$, or the problem is utterly trivial. For one approach, think about taking a derivative of the function $1 / (1 - x)$; this has been done here many times before.

Comment: @user Yes, I meant that; thanks for noticing. I have been directed by my professor that he specifically wants it to be done in the fashion that I've began

Comment: You're saying $\frac{s}{2} = \frac{-n}{2^{n+1}} + \sum_{i=1}^n 2^{-i}$. But the latter sum has a formula that you have probably already seen.

Comment: You have also made a mistake in computing s/2.  There is a 'n' in the numerator which should be '1'.

Comment: @Ian I've seen a formula for that yes, awhile ago though. I'll try that now.

Comment: @Ian Forgot to comment back after I got it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in the comments, looking at the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ gives the answer, but you have mentioned you have been instructed to solve it using this method.
Notice that you almost reached a solution! You have 
$$ \frac{s}{2} = \frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{n}{2^{n+1}}$$
The first part of the right hand side is a sum of a geometric sequence. Use this!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i x^i = \sum_{i=1}^n x \frac d {dx} x^i = x \frac d {dx} \sum_{i=1}^n x^i = x \frac d {dx}\  \frac{x - x^{n+1}}{1-x} = \cdots
$$
(Now evaluate the derivative and then substitute $\dfrac 1 2$ for $x$.)